# Prove every linear graph is Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm reading Munkres Topology book and I've been a bit stumped by this proof. I'm trying to visualize what's going on here and would appreciate any feedback on this. For context, here is the proof[image: proof of lemma]
Based off of the definition above this proof, I believe A notates an arc, which is defined to be something homeomorphic to the unit interval [0,1]. I drew out a topological space $X$ and two closed, disjoint subsets  $B$ and $C$ within $X$. I think the next part is the main issue.After I drew out the arcs, I tried to choose disjoint $U$ and $V$s, using the definition that says open edges are the interior of A. However, I'm not sure if I'm supposed to interpret that as open edges. Furthermore, I think that makes what I'm thinking incorrect, because if an endpoint (aka vertex) of any of the arcs land directly in $B$ or $C$, then the $U$ or $V$ neighborhood won't contain it and thus doesn't contain the intersection of $B$ and $A$ or $C$ and $A$. Here's my sketch:
[image: sketch]
Can anyone point me in the right direction? I appreciate any help. In case it is needed, here is the definition that is listed above the proof. The definition and the lemma are the first two things in the section, so this is all that has been covered out of Sec 83 so far. [image: def]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have overlooked the second sentence of the proof: All vertices of the graph are in either $B$ or $C$. The reason this is "without loss of generality" is that the vertices form a discrete subspace of $X$, so for arbitrary closed $B, C$, you can add any missing vertices to one or the other set without changing that the sets are closed. So the cases in your example with endpoints outside both $B$ and $C$ cannot occur.

On the other hand, there are some significant possibilities that can occur, but you did not include in your example.

- It is possible for both vertices of $A_\alpha$ to lie in the same set, indeed for the entirety of $A_\alpha$ to lie within one or the other set.
- It is also possible for $A_\alpha$ to leave one of the sets, then later re-enter that set. After which it could leave it again. It is even possible for $A_\alpha$ to leave and re-enter a set infinitely many times. And it can do the same for the other set as well. In fact, as $B$ and $C$ are not required to be connected, $A_\alpha$ could even do this uncountably many times (consider $B\cap A_\alpha$ to be the image of the Cantor set, and $C\cap A_\alpha$ to be a smaller Cantor-style set within one of the intervals where $A_\alpha$ is not in $B$).

However, because we already know that $[0,1]$ is normal, $A_\alpha$ has to be normal as well, since it is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. Since $A_\alpha$ is closed, so are its intersections with $B$ and $C$. Thus by the normality of $A_\alpha$, the desired open sets $U_\alpha, V_\alpha$ must exist, regardless of how $B\cap A_\alpha$ and $C\cap A_\alpha$ are interweaved. If $A_\alpha$ lies entirely in $B$, then $C\cap A_\alpha = \emptyset$, but then we can take $U_\alpha = A_\alpha$ and $V_\alpha = \emptyset$. Both are open subsets of $A_\alpha$.

I hope that helps to clear up some of your confusion. I am not sure why you think that the definition of "open edge" to refer to the interior of an edge (i.e., everything except the two endpoints) is relevant here. The sets $U_\alpha, V_\alpha$ are open sets of $A_\alpha$, not of its interior.

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks! I see where my misconceptions were. My last question is how do we know [0,1] is normal? I know that means that there exist disjoint open sets that contain any two disjoint closed sets, but are we able to determine that [0,1] is normal without specifying what the space we're in or what the topology on the space is?

Comment: $[0.1]$ is the interval on the Real line. Its topology is certainly the most well-studied topology in mathematics. Munkres has a proof (though possibly as an exercise).